# Имя массива - ссылка или указатель? С++

Tags: c++, функции, указатели, ссылки

Заранее прошу прощения, если вопрос слишком простой.
Учусь по самоучителю Васильева А. Н.
В одной из глав, посвященной передаче массива аргументом функции, автор говорит, цитата: "...Учитывая то обстоятельство, что имя массива является ссылкой на первый его элемент...".
А уже страницу спустя, пишет следующее: "...Поэтому разумнее, принимая во внимание сказанное, передавать массив в виде указателя, благо таковым является имя массива..."

Ранее я читал формулировку, что ссылка, это утрированно указатель со скрытым адресом. Но все-таки это разные понятия.
Так что же все-таки такое имя массива?

И вопрос на засыпку, почему при передаче массива аргументом, для указателя при объявлении используется "*", а для ссылки "&" - нет?

Comment: Имя массива - это именно имя массива, при этом оно может в подходящем контексте неявно преобразовываться в указатель на первый элемент или в ссылку на массив. *"...Учитывая то обстоятельство, что имя массива является ссылкой на первый его элемент..."* - можете выкинуть книжку в мусор. "вопрос на засыпку" - для передачи массива по ссылке использовать & придется, заметьте, что у аргументов функции альтернативные правила для объявения типов аргументов, и аргумент с типом массив на самом деле имеет тип указатель.

Comment: Лучше почитайте первоисточник -- [K&R](https://kremlin.cc/k&r.pdf)

Comment: Да, посоветовали одну тему со схожим смыслом. Что ж, этот автор и ранее косячил, замечал. 
Спасибо за пояснение, значит он ошибся.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Это всё разные типы

- `int [ ]` массив
- `int ( & ) [ ]` ссылка на массив
- `int ( * ) [ ]` указатель на массив
- `int *` указатель на первый элемент

Есть много способов передачи массивов аргументом. Рассмотрим только три *(массивы функциям по значению полностью не передаются)* :

- указатель на первый элемент
- указатель на массив
- ссылка на массив

Классически передают все указатель на первый элемент, так как это даёт универсальность функции, для обработки массивов разного размера. А в остальных случаях функция будет способна работать только с массивов определённого размера, так как типы например `int [2]` и `int [4]` - разные.

```c++
// указатель на первый элемент

// void fun6(int * x) фактически
void fun6(int x[6]){    
}

// void fun12(int * x) фактически
void fun12(int x[12]){    
}

// ссылка на массив

void funl6(int (&x)[6]){
}

void funl12(int (&x)[12]){
}

// указатель на массив

void funp6(int (*x)[6]){
}

void funp12(int (*x)[12]){
}

int main(){
    int a[6];
    int b[12];
    fun6(a);
    fun6(b);
    fun12(a);
    fun12(b);
    funl6(a);
    //funl6(b); ошибка разных типов
    //funl12(a); ошибка разных типов
    funl12(b);
    funp6(&a);
    //funp6(&b); ошибка разных типов
    //funp12(&a); ошибка разных типов
    funp12(&b);
}
```

Первые функции на самом деле принимают указатель на первый элемент и им не важны размеры массивов. Они универсальны.
В остальных случаях функции принимают только массивы указанного размера.

Answer (score -2):

Конечно указатель, а как иначе:

```
#include <iostream>


int main()
{
    int *arr = new int[5]{1,2,3,4,5};
    
    std::cout << *arr << std::endl;

    delete []arr;

    return 0;
}
```